# What causes MySQL cardinality to decrease?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, cardinality

In our production MySQL systems we have some queries that normally will take less then 2 seconds to execute but some times they will run for over a minute. Every time one of these queries runs long we check the indexing and find that the cardinality has dropped on the same VARCHAR(25) field. We run MySQL as a cluster of master with multiple slaves and we will find that the cardinality on just that slow system with have decreased, the value will remain high on all other servers. When the value drops it will go from about 20k-30k (high value) down to only a few hundred. Running the ANALYZE TABLE command fixes the cardinality and brings it backup to 20k-30k and the query runs fast again.

I have started monitoring the cardinality on all tables to see how this value changes over time. I understand that cardinality will go up as new data is added, and I would expect it to go down as records are deleted but this table very rarely gets records deleted yet the value will go up and down every time I look at it.

MySQL 5.5.8 InnoDB

CentOS 5.7

Any ideas on what I should be looking for?
COUT(*) = 402259

Comment: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44760 ?

Comment: The bug 44760 looks suspiciously similar if not for the fact that I am using InnoDB not ndbcluster and the bug was reported in version 5.1 and would hope that the 5.5 I am using would not a such an old bug. Still very interesting.

Comment: Did you find a reason for this???

Comment: I have not found a reason for falling cardinality or a work around to the problem it causes. We know that when our tables have high cardinality, often after a table has been optimized, our queries are very fast. Cardinality on tables with high activity fluctuates throughout the day. If cardinality drops by more then 40%, the performance of queries on that table tank and some times lock. Any query that takes longer then 60 seconds is killed. We also have Icinga monitoring for falling cardinality to let us know before it happens. No solutions yet.

Answer (score 1):

The stats of InnoDB tables are approximate, not accurate. So, if you want to know the exact cardinality of a field, you may run this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT field_name) FROM table_name
```

Comment: All slaves have identical counts to the master 7657. When I use SHOW INDEXES FROM table_name I get cardinality counts of 9305 on the master, and 21189,11503,7742 & 6913 on the slaves. All slaves are zero seconds behind the master. The numbers remanded unchanged for a few minutes then the slave with 21189 dropped to 7742 while all the other slaves and the master remained the same.

Comment: That is possible and very normal. In fact, it is hard to get the same stats on different server even if they have the exact same data. There are few factors behind that. The main factor is the way InnoDB stores data and indexes. It used B-Tree for indexes, where the cardinality is shown from. Try to check the size of the files on the master and slaves, it will not be the same.